# jQuery UI Resizable Plugin – Scaling a <div> AND the contents within?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins

Does anybody have a clue, if it's possible to resize a `<div>` and the content (here: images)
within without using "`alsoResize` in combination with a class/id name".

In other words: Is there a workaround for:

```
 $('DIV').resizable({ handles: 'se', alsoResize: 'ITS CHILDREN' });
```

or are just class/id names allowed for `alsoResize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try :

```
$('DIV').resizable({ handles: 'se', alsoResize: 'img' });
```

or set your images Width & Height to % values.

By the way, `class/id names` are allowed for `alsoResize`.

Comment: Of course, yes, class and ids are allowed.
Yes, sure it works if I put alsoResize: 'img', I already tried this solution. But then all 'img's will scale. I need to resize just one container and its children images at a time. The divs are created dynamically, so it would be hard to hard-code every (random) id. I think.