# Jquery/UI/Effects/Scale plugin not working on images

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, scale, image-scaling

I'm using the [JqueryUI/Effects/Scale plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Scale) to shrink/grow divs and the content inside.  It works great for text and even embedded youtube clips, but doesn't scale images contained within.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Is it supposed to scale images?  [Look at this other thread about a different plugin.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396279/jquery-ui-resizable-plugin-scaling-a-div-and-the-contents-within)

Comment: Adding a width="100%" attr to my images seems to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396279/jquery-ui-resizable-plugin-scaling-a-div-and-the-contents-within), using another UI plugin with a similar issue, the ultimate solution was to set the image size as a percentage.